# How can I check if file_get_contents has POST?

Tags: php

Hi I need to check if file_get_contents posts data to the server.. my script look like this

```
<?php
$foo = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com");

if ($_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD] == POST)
{
// do action
}

echo $foo;
?>
```

I know that file_get_contents stops my script, any help is appreciated

Comment: This question makes no sense. Try explaining what you expected the code to do that it's not doing.

Comment: can you tell me more what you want to do ?

Comment: what the hell is this? :)

Comment: I needed to capture a URL and check if its contents had ($_POST)... If the contents did post, then echo $_POST['name'] for example.. Does that make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `file_get_contents` call never sends POST data to the server - just a a simple GET request. So you dont have anything in your `$_POST` var.

Exceptions:

- The other server add some POST data on their own.
- You pass an context to file_get_contents, which changes the request to a POST request

Comment: Can you give me an example of how this is done? my goal is once I have called the url, then to capture any $i_POST data that would be submitted to the server

Comment: To get you right.. FileA.php calls `file_get_contents('.../FileB.php')` and after that call FileA  should wait till FileB recives some Post requests from somewhere else and return the recived data?